# Should NSWindowController always be the superclass of a window controller?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

When reading Apple's Cocoa tutorial, the window controller is just a regular class and while understand that this is perfectly fine I suppose, wouldn't it be better to subclass NSWindowController?

If I get this right, NSWindowController is a convenience class which already has a lot of the functionality required by a window controller implemented, right?

Is there any reason why you would not use this class?

Comment: which tutorial were you reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to. I've sometimes implemented controllers for a window that inherited from `NSObject`, if I didn't really need the added functionality of `NSWindowController`.